# Calculating coloumn based on choice coloumn

Tags: calculated-column, choice-field

I'm new to sharepoint and I wanted to create list about employee information, in which Experince level of employee is calculated based on its designation where, Experience level is text area and designation is choice coloumn. For an example,

There is one multiple choice field like Manager,Associate,Trainee,..etc and a single line field in which the value associated to it should be directly be inserted into it. For eg- If I select Manager from mulitple choice field then 7-8 yrs should be displayed in single line of text field automatically or if I select Associate from mulitple choice field then 5-6 yrs should be displayed in single line of text field automatically or similarly. For that should I create a lookup or suggest me some solution?

Comment: It's easy to create a calculation in SharePoint. But first the input fields and the processing logic needs to be defined. So, please edit your question and provide the details: what are the input fields? What is the processing logic? SharePoint calculated columns can use the format and syntax of many Excel formulas. So, If you can work out your logic in Excel with formulas, it can probably be applied to a SharePoint calculated column.  Please edit your question and provide the data and rules.

Comment: There is one multiple choice field like Manager,Associate,Trainee,..etc and a single line field in which the value associated to it should be directly be inserted into it. For eg- If I select Manager from mulitple choice field then 7-8 yrs should be displayed in single line of text field automatically or if I select Associate from mulitple choice field then 5-6 yrs should be displayed in single line of text field automatically or similarly. For that should I create a lookup or suggest me some solution?

Comment: Please put that info into your question, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new SharePoint list called "EExperience" with two fields: Title and Experience. Fill this list with the values for each title and the appropriate value in the experience field.

Then go back to the employee information list and add a column called "Manager" that has the data type "Lookup". Follow the dialog and select the list "EExperience" you created above. Make "Title" the primary selection field and tick the box for the "Experience" field.

Now, when you add a new item in the Information list, the "Manager" field will be a drop-down. When you select a value, for example "Manager", the experience field for the "Manager" value will be filled with the value that the "EExperience" has for the "Manager" value.

Hope this makes sense. Please pipe up if you need more help.